# Error loading file stored in Google Cloud Storage to Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been trying to create a job to **load** a compressed json file from Google Cloud Storage to a Google BigQuery table. I have read/write access in both Google Cloud Storage and Google BigQuery. Also, the uploaded file belongs in the same project as the BigQuery one.

The problem happens when I access to the resource behind this url https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/NUMERIC_ID/jobs by means of a  **POST** request. The content of the request to the abovementioned resource can be found as follows:

```
{
"kind" : "bigquery#job",
"projectId" : NUMERIC_ID,
"configuration": {
    "load": {
        "sourceUris": ["gs://bucket_name/document.json.gz"],
        "schema": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "INTEGER"
                },
                {
                    "name": "date",
                    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
                },
                {
                    "name": "user_agent",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "queried_key",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "user_country",
                    "type": "STRING"
                },
                {
                    "name": "duration",
                    "type": "INTEGER"
                },
                {
                    "name": "target",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ]
        },
        "destinationTable": {
            "datasetId": "DATASET_NAME",
            "projectId": NUMERIC_ID,
            "tableId": "TABLE_ID"
        }
    }
}
```

}

However, the error doesn't make any sense and can also be found below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0: "
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0: "
    }
}
```

I know the problem doesn't lie either in the project id or in the access token placed in the authentication header, because I have successfully created an empty table before. Also I specify the content-type header to be `application/json` which I don't think is the issue here, because the body content should be json encoded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The request looks okay to me. There is an extra comma at the end of the "target" field in the schema which might be making the API think you have 0 job-configurations.

Comment: Thank you, but that comma was a typo caused because there were more elements in the schema which I deleted to make the body simpler for the question. The issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP request is malformed -- BigQuery doesn't recognize this as a load job at all.
You need to look into the POST request, and check the body you send.

You need to ensure that all the above (which seams correct) is the `body` of the POST call. The above `Json` should be on a single line, and if you manually creating the multipart message, make sure there is an extra newline between the headers and body of each MIME type.

If you are using some sort of library, make sure the body is not expected in some other form, like resource, content, or body. I've seen libraries that use these differently.

Try out the BigQuery API explorer: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert and ensure your request body matches the one made by the API.

Comment: I followed the provided link and discovered that it worked. The difference is that they don't use the upload endpoint (they use https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/NUMERIC_ID/jobs instead of https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/NUMERIC_ID/jobs). Moreover they add a query parameter called ```key``` which must be equals to the access token. It still doesn't make any sense but at least it works. Thanks